# Check if a C enum exists

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, enums, nsstring

How would I check that **NSRegularExpressionSearch** exists before using it?

```
enum {
  NSCaseInsensitiveSearch = 1,
  NSLiteralSearch = 2,
  NSBackwardsSearch = 4,
  NSAnchoredSearch = 8,
  NSNumericSearch = 64,
  NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch = 128,
  NSWidthInsensitiveSearch = 256,
  NSForcedOrderingSearch = 512,
  NSRegularExpressionSearch = 1024
};
```

Update- I want to compile against the latest SDK and check at runtime if NSRegularExpressionSearch exists.

Comment: Does the fact that the program won't compile without the definition help?

Comment: Not really :) The app needs to be compatible with previous versions of the OS that don't include NSRegularExpressionSearch.

Comment: @christo16: Well, that makes no sense.  Either the name is defined (and it compiles) or the name is undefined (and it doesn't compile).

Comment: @S.Lott I think he wants to compile against a current SDK and determine at runtime whether the version of iPhone OS he is using has support for regular expression compares.

Comment: @JeremyP: Interesting guess.  christo16 can *want* that.  I don't see how it's possible in any way to not compile correctly and still somehow check something at run-time.  I'm hoping for a corrections to the question that will explain exactly what's supposed to happen.

Comment: @S.Lott because you can compile against (say) the 3.2 SDK which has the define but then have it deploy on an iPhone with an earlier runtime where the define is obviously meaningless, but the runtime doesn't support regular expression searching.

Comment: @JeremyP: And you've tried this?  The iPhone doesn't reject the software built with the wrong SDK?

Comment: No I haven't tried it, but it is common to do this sort of thing on Mac OS X.  Stuff compiled with the 10.6 API will run on 10.5 (and 10.4 if you are lucky) provided you only use features that were available in the environment you are running in.  At the machine level, the API consists of obj_msg_send() and a few other C functions.  id's are id's in any version of Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSRegularExpressionSearch` is only compiled when

```
#if __IPHONE_3_2 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
```

So you need to check that the current operating system is 3.2 or later.

```
if ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] >= 3.2 ) {}
```

In other cases you might check that a class exists or that an instance responds to a selector, but NSString did not change other than that enum.  For example, if there was an enum associated with gesture recognizers you could use one of the following:

```
if ( NSClassFromString( @"UIGestureRecognizer" ) != nil ) {}
if ( [someView respondsToSelector:@selector(gestureRecognizers)] ) {}
```

For another example, see how Apple handles the UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM macro.

Edit:

A version number to check besides the system version is `NSFoundationVersionNumber`.

```
if ( NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iPhoneOS_3_1 ) {}
```

That is more closely tied to NSString, but there is no constant for 3.2 in the 3.2 headers.

Comment: I was trying to avoid checking by OS version, as that is usually a bad practice.  But it looks like the only way to check.

Answer (score 1):

The question title is not correct. Your question is not whether NSRegularExpressionSearch exists. (Yes, it exists at compile time with an SDK >= 3.2.) Your question is whether methods like `rangeOfString:options:` can correctly interpret the option bit for regular expression at runtime.

Since this is a question purely about the behavior of a function, one obvious way to figure it out is to do an experiment. Do something that you know will succeed when support is there but will fail when it isn't.

We can attempt a match using a regular expression that matches a string, but where the regex string does not literally exists in the string, so that if it doesn't understand the regex option it will do a literal match and fail. For example,

```
if ([@"b" rangeOfString:@"." options:NSRegularExpressionSearch].location != NSNotFound) {
    // NSRegularExpressionSearch supported
}
```